# Android getting current calendarview's year, month

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

In calendarview, at first I can set date but I cannot get which month and year when I click two buttons that change calendar to previous month or next month.
And even more, calendarview supports swipe to go previous or next month,
but I cannot get year and month info of now displaying calendar.
How can I get year and month info of seeing (now displaying) calendar??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5oYF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as8tn.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateto = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                updateLabe2();


            }

        };
        To.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), dateto, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
});
  public void updateLabe2()
{
String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    To.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
//here To is editbox
}
```

Comment: for example, today is nov 13, when i start calendar widget, i can get month and year info because initially calendar is focused on today. but when i click button to go previous or next month, then calendar changes oct 2018 or dec 2018

Comment: and calendar is still focused on today, nov 13. until i click date on calendar, with just swipe and click button, i cannot get renewed data of month and year.

Comment: use this for initilizationCalendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
so now what u want??

Comment: i want get displaying calendar's month and year data. not focused.
when we click buttons beside of basic calendarview widget,
at first there will be today (nov 2018) but when i click next button(exactly 
button that right side of "november 2018"), widget shows me dec 2018 but
i cannot get date data that represents 2018-12-**.

Comment: if you have enough time, please see pic of my edited question.